# Kotlin : How to pass image from Activity to Fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

Im trying to pass an image from my Activity ViewModel to Fragment, the Fragment Receive the data but it doesnt showed up on the fragment. Here is my code

Main Activity ViewModel

```
    val storageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().reference.child("Users/$nisSiswa.png")
        val file = File.createTempFile("image", "png")
        storageRef.getFile(file).addOnSuccessListener {
            val bitmap : Bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.absolutePath)
            val bitmapString = ByteArrayOutputStream()
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bitmapString)
            val byteArray : ByteArray = bitmapString.toByteArray()
            profileBundle.putByteArray("foto", byteArray)
            profilFragment.arguments = profileBundle
            crashlytics.log("Bundle Dikirimkan ke Fragment")
            loadingDialog.dismissLoading()
        }
```

And here is my fragment Code to retrieve the image

```
super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        binding.tvNamaSiswa.setText(arguments?.getString("nama"))
        binding.tvNisSiswa.setText(arguments?.getString("nis"))
        binding.tvEmailSiswa.setText(arguments?.getString("email"))
        val byteFoto = arguments?.getByteArray("foto")
        if (byteFoto != null) {
            crashlytics.log("Data Berhasil Diterima Profile Fragment")
            val bitmapFoto : Bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteFoto,0, DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE)
            val encoded : ByteArray? = Base64.decode(byteFoto, Base64.DEFAULT)
            val bitmap = encoded?.let { BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(encoded, 0, it.size) }
            binding.ivProfil.setImageBitmap(bitmapFoto)
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this.context, "File Bitmap Kosong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            binding.ivProfil.setImageResource(R.drawable.user_foto)
        }
```

Comment: But you did not tell if byteFoto was null or not.

Comment: Further it makes no sense to do a base64 decode as you did not base64 encode anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't really be passing bitmaps around in `Bundle`s, they're not meant for large amounts of data. It would be better to pass that string reference you're using to fetch it (`"Users/$nisSiswa.png"`) and let the `Fragment` handle fetching and displaying it.

Or use a `ViewModel` that the activity can pass a reference to, so the data fetch happens, and the fragment `observe`s it and displays the current data.

You should also probably be using a library like [Glide](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/) to display your images, which is [the official recommendation](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap) - just makes things easier for you!

Comment: now im just passing image URI, i cant believe i dont recognize such an easy solution. thx for answering my question. Have a good day sir